# Best practices for extensions of Types in swift

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I have been using extensions a lot in my projects because of the level of customisation which I find delightful. They work neatly - so no worries there.

I you want to make an extension on your class, normally you would declare it just outside the class, but in the **same file**.

If I in want to make an extension on a Type like 'Array' then I would declare the extension outside of the class, but in the same file where I need the extended functionality. However, this extended functionality of 'Array' will now be available in all files in my project.

My question is: **If I know I will need some extended functionality in the entire project, is there any good/bad practices in terms if where I declare this extension?**

*My concern* is that when using the new functionality in other files in the project, they may have to create a reference to the file where the extension is declared. Although I have no idea about how this actually works. Just trying to make sure I'm not unintentionally interconnecting all files with a particular viewcontroller/model or likewise.

Comment: Not really! Yeah can declare your extension anywhere in your project! What i do is I make a swift file and name it my extensions and then have all of my extensions there

Comment: https://medium.com/@iamolchavan/extension-in-swift-adc0421a61c5

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. It seems like the "Type+Extension" is the way to go. :=) I will look into the article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]I usually don't implement extension anywhere across ViewControllers because if 5 VCs need 5 different extension functionalitis for an **Array** then we have to write **extension Array { }** in 5 VCs which will make it hard to navigate and find the implementation for extended functionalities. So what I actually do is make an Extension folder in project hierarcy Where I will make a file named Array+Extension.swift. All the functions releted to array extension will go inside Array+Extension file. The above image will give you a clear picture.